# Pi Camera streaming via gpio

Tags: gpio, camera

is there a way to transfer the video stream from one raspberry pi to another via gpio pins? One pi is In a closed container with the camera and the other pi drives the user interface. Networking is sadly not an option.

Thanks

Comment: Why is networking not possible? If you can run wires from the pins you should also be able to do that from a network interface... What is stopping you from using a network connection?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you should be able to use the SPI interface.

The SPI interface can handle up to 10Mbps.

Ref.:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/spi/README.md

http://www.eeherald.com/section/design-guide/esmod12.html